# Regular Expression Please

Tags: regex

What would the regular expression be to find all instances of the following;

```
file:///F|/rah/title.txt (47 of 199) [8/27/03 11:21:39 PM]</p><p class="Griegs3">
file:///F|/rah/title.txt
```

Where the (47 of 199) changes to (48 of 199) etc.  Bu I want to match from file:// in the first line to .txt in the second

What I have been ased to do is go through around 60 files and find all instances of the above within them.  There are likely to be 1000's of instances and I just wanted to be able to open notepad++ and run a macro over all the files matching and then removing the instances.

Comment: All instances of what? What language?

Comment: No language, i just want the regular expression so i can do a find and replace in something like Notepad++

Comment: you'll need to figure out what you want, first.

Comment: And what specifically are you looking for?  I mean, why not just search for (without regexes) "file:///F|" etc., up to what changes?

Comment: What's the surrounding text like?

Comment: Because there are over 1000 instances spread over 60+ files and I'd like to just have a regex that i could use that would then highlight the line in notepad++ which i can then hit delete on

Comment: the surrounding text is simply text from our now deleted cms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information this is a bit unclear, but here's my stab at it:

```
file:.*\(\d+\s*of\s*\d+\).+[\r\n]*file:.+[\r\n]*
```

As seen on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/OiaDaWF7KT)

This will match the a line containing `(x of y)` and the line right after it.
Both lines have to start with `file:`.

---

> **EDIT:** I tested the regex and it works. However, Notepad++ doesn't support multiline regex.
>   See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441044/multiline-regular-expression-search-and-replace).

Here's a more generic regex which will match any lines starting with `file:`

```
^file:.+[\r\n]*
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I have updated the question so that it hopefully makes more sense

Comment: fat chance of me actually getting them to purchase anything at this place!  :)  But thatks for the heads up, it makes some sense and maybe i can run two macros in notepad++ one after the other

Answer (score 0):

`/file\:\/\/\/F\|\/rah\/title\.txt\ \(47\ of\ 199\)\ \[8\/27\/03\ 11\:21\:39\ PM\]\<\/p\>\<p\ class\=\"Griegs3\"\>\nfile\:\/\/\/F\|\/rah\/title\.txt/`

(blame quotemeta, not me, for the liberal escaping.)

Comment: '47 of 199' changes for each instance so the next one will be '48 of 199' and so on so i need that bit to be ignored