# Find multiple lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to find a paragraph?

For instance I want to search for this code:

```
<?php
    $radio_buttons++;
  }
?>
```

But when I try to copy that into the search box it only copies the first line, `<?php`.

It seems like there is definitely a way to do this, but I just can't find it. Maybe it is an addon?

Comment: I'm on a Mac right now so can't check, but I seem to recall that Notepad++ allows you to specify regular expression in the search field?

Comment: Yes it does but I still can't paste in more then a single line

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405002/missing-desired-features-in-notepad. Looks like Notepad++ doesn't support multi-line search yet. There might a plugin for it but none that I've heard of.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I wrote a multiline search and replace add on for Notepad++, check it out here:
http://www.phdesign.com.au/programming/toolbucket-multi-line-search-plugin-for-notepad/

[image: ToolBucket Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [phdesign.com.au](http://www.phdesign.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/ToolBucket3.png))</sub>

Comment: This is great stuff. Thank you.. It was still a problem many months later and this works perfectly. If I did have just oneee tiny nitpick it is that using ctral + A to select all, which I do to erase a previous search does not seem to work.

Comment: Thank you for developing that very useful tools. I've installed them to my desktop and portable versions of Notepad++. I'll recommend them to my colleagues.

Comment: +1 and thank you! I like that you made the find and replace similar to dreamweaver's GUI. The only thing missing is the option to save regexes.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the useful tool. @t.mikael.d the current version of the plugin already saves all previously used regexes, you can use these regexes by clicking the very small button with the calendar icon between the Find/Replace text boxes and the buttons on the right.

Comment: The plugin does not work with me with Notepad++ 5.x.x. But it works like charm with 6.x.x

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful plug-in, I work with lots of documents that require a multi-line search and replace feature. It's so nice that you have provided this great tool for the community.  Thank you!!

Comment: There is one deal-breaker for me with this plugin: no option to replace in all open documents (like the default search has)

Comment: Great plugin Paul..  Is there also an option to replace text in files without opening them?  i.e. giving it the directory to replace the text in it?  Thanks

Comment: @Mike no there is now. Good idea bit its not possible with the windows file system POE of windows 10

Comment: @phdesign I just tried to install this plugin, sadly it doesn't seem to be compatible with that latest version of Notepad++, there isn't a 64bit version available is there?

Comment: There is support for 64-bit now (since June 2017).

Answer (score 23):

As [Xenovoyance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489128/find-multiple-lines-in-notepad/5489251#5489251) suggests, it is possible with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (also found in menu option **TextFX** > **TextFX Quick** > **Find/Replace**):

Just select your text to find, then invoke that option...
[image: Multi line find/replace]

**UPDATE:** User [Żabojad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255091/abojad) made me realise that in the latest releases of Notepad++, the "**TextFX**" plugin is not installed by default, so first you'll have to do one of two things:

1. The easiest one: Go to menu option **Plugins** > **Plugin Manager** > **Show Plugin Manager**, scroll the available plugin list to "**TextFX Characters**" and install it. 
   [image: Install from Plugin Manager]
2. The above way should work, but otherwise you'll have go to this page : http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/
   and download file `TextFX.v0.26.unicode.bin.zip` 
   [image: Download TextFX Characters]
   then extract its contents (don't just copy zip file) to the `\plugins` subfolder of the Notepad++ Install Folder
   [image: Copy dll to Notepad++ plugins folder]

After restarting Notepad++ you'll see the menu entry **TextFX**.

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin doesn't seem to support editing multiple open documents either.

Comment: Ctrl+R didn't work for me until I went into Settings > Shortcut Mapper, and clicked on the "Reload from disk" line and clicked Clear to remove the conflicting Ctrl+R shortcut.

Answer (score 9):

Since **Notepad++ 6.0** the regular expression search for multiple lines works.

The search for your code would be something like

```
<?php.*\r\n.*$radio_buttons++;.*\r\n.*}.*\r\n.*?>
```

**.*** is just wildcard for any number of characters (except line breaks). You can also toggle a checkbox in the Notepad++ dialog (called **. matches newline**) to include line breaks.

For a detailed description see the top answer of this question:

[Find CRLF in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad)

Answer (score 8):

`Cntrl+C` the above text you want to find and `Cntrl+V` it into a new blank document in Notepad++, then Select it again and hit `Cntrl+F` . You will see your text into the "find" field with tabbed spaces as the line breaks. No need for plugins.

Comment: Confirmed in Notepad++ 6.6.9. You can check the actual search string in the `<Find ...>` sections within `<FindHistory...>` in Notepad++'s "config.xml" file.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge Notepad++ doesn't support multi-line regular expressions, so you'll have to do this by replacing every line break with the representative line break characters for your operating system (most likely `\r\n`).  See [Find CRLF in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad) for details.

Comment: The problem is if you paste the paragraph into Search box, all you get is '<?php'. That is an awful lot of work just to type one paragraph into a search box.

Comment: Not really - you can use the extended search to replace all `\r\n`s with some unused character (tilde, pipe, etc.), then use the non-extended search to replace that character with `\r\n` again (with non-extended `\r\n` will not create new lines).  Voila - the search string.  Also, you can make a macro out of this fairly easily.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following thread on a related subject: [Multiline Regular Expression search and replace!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441044/multiline-regular-expression-search-and-replace)

Recommend that you try out CTRL + R!

Comment: trying CTRL + R it does not seem to be working. Not sure which options to have selected yet.

Comment: I just tried it on my machine here (notepad++ 5.8.6) and I could search for a multi-line blog of text. Perhaps running an older version?

Comment: yep I was on 5.8.6 and actually just updated to .7 it seems to work sometimes** like in a paragraph on a txt file but doesnt seem to like when searching for a block of code with white space between it. Maybe it is an option I am missing.

Comment: Just realized "selection" was ticked off it seems to work now! Thanks!

Comment: It's really through the plugins Notepad++ really start to shine. Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

Multiple lines can be passed to search and replace fields only when lines endings are set to Unix form. This can be done via *Edit>EOL Conversion>Unix*

Then you can manually copy multiple line paragraph to search field.

After that, just convert line endings back to Windows via *Edit>EOL Conversion>Windows*

Comment: Nice, no need any extra plugin

Answer (score 2):

For a Notepad++ v5.8.7+ there is no TextFX plugin for Unicode installed by default, so in order to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> you need to install `TextFX Characters` [plugin](http://textfx.no-ip.com/textfx/) with Plugin Manager.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:
Change the search mode to Extended and replace "return-newline"s with `\r\n`
eg
`<?php\r\n    $radio_buttons++;\r\n  }\r\n?>`
Problem is you need to know the white space (not shown above). 
Maybe a regex could work?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the TextFX menu option. That looks like it supports multiple line searching.

Answer (score 0):

in the latest notepad++, simply select all the multiline text you want to search and press ctrl+f, it will automatically put the text to be searched in the search field formatted for multiline search.

Comment: What does *"latest"* mean? Please state the Notepad++ version number; latest is not a useful term.