# In which html-editor can I ignore NewLine when searching for a text?

Tags: html, html-editor

I have a big html file that was split in lines in notepad++ (I had a very long line: 110.000 characters). This inserted NewLine characters in the text. So if I search for "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" there is a possibility that it wont come up as search result because notepad++ added in a NewLine between words. So how can I ignore NewLine when searching for a text? In which html-editor can I do this?

Comment: You say "... there is a possibility that it won't come up... ". Can you give an example of when notepad++ is not able to find it? Or is it just an assumption that this is possible?

Comment: @ Darian: In my original file I had: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". After the line split operation notepad++ inserted a new line after the "fox" word. So if I search for "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" it wont come up as search result because the text now is: "The quick brown fox[[NEWLINE]] jumps over the lazy dog"

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use a regular expression in notepad++ to match either a space or a newline, or a newline and a space.

I do know know which one you should use, however, but this may get you on your way.

My best guess is to use something like `(\s\n|\n\s)` between words, but I could not get this to work.

EDIT: I think your question is [already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489128/find-multiple-lines-in-notepad)

Comment: In the link both the search string and searchable text is multiline, so there is equality in a normal string comparison. In my case the search string is not multiline, so there is no equality in a normal string comparison.