# A hex viewer / editor plugin for Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have had a look through the plugins as well as searched the forum for Notepad++ and have not seen a solution to editing data as hex in [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++).

I am after the same kind of functionality that [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) offers (see the screenshot below) where you can edit the document either directly or via entering new hex characters.

[image: Screenshot from UltraEdit's hex editor]

Comment: How is such an up-voted question with several up-voted answers marked as off-topic?  Does this send a message to admin??

Comment: @Michael I don't think anyone thinks this is a bad question. People may just think it would fit better on another site, like Super User or Software Recommendations.

Comment: Sometimes I wish all the sites just folded into StackOverflow as it is sometimes really hard to pick one that fits best. And if you do then that site generally gets less attention than SO itself.

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/chcg/NPP_HexEdit/releases) and [this](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14264/i-made-hexeditor-x64-working-what-next)

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Why not get it included so that it is available via the Plugins Admin

Comment: Had a big struggle, it was due to wrapping of content inside the variable with a single quote. Using an  eval we were able to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733338/shell-script-remove-first-and-last-quote-from-a-variable , though it is not clear to me why it is getting wrapped inside single quotes

Answer (score 56):

There is an old plugin called **HEX Editor** [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/).

According to [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/163006) it does not work on newer versions of Notepad++ and might have some stability issues, but it still could be useful depending on your needs.

Comment: Roger that.  It does not work in Notepad++ v6.5.  If anyone has an answer to this question for recent versions of Notepad++, that would be great.

Comment: Moving HexEditor.dll back from Notepad++\plugins\disabled to Notepad++\disabled works for me in Notepad++ v6.5 UNICODE (Build time: 28 Sep 2013 - 22:29:19). I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn I think you mean "to Notepad++\plugins" Works for me too.

Comment: @Aleksandr Dubinsky Yes, you're right, thanks! So it's:
moving HexEditor.dll back from Notepad++\plugins\disabled to Notepad++\plugins works for me in Notepad++ v6.5 UNICODE (Build time: 28 Sep 2013 - 22:29:19). I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I just installed it and it seems to work fine on 6.6.9.

Comment: nablex's answer is a good workaround as well

Comment: Seems to work in 6.8.8 as well.

Comment: Plugin HEX-editor with a good stability works in Notepad++ 7.5.4

Answer (score 47):

Is a completely different (but still free) application an option? I use [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/), and it serves me better than the Notepad++ plugin. It can calculate hashes, open memory of a process, it is fast at opening files of any size, and it works exceptionally well with the clipboard.

I used to use the Notepad++ plugin, but not anymore.

Answer (score 13):

According to some comments on Super User it still works :) It just should be copied back to the plugins folder (if it's in the disabled folder) or downloaded from [Plugins Central](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central). I have downloaded it a few minutes ago and succeeded in using it.

Of course, be warned: this plugin COULD be unstable in some situations - that's why it was disabled.

Comment: None of the Hex editor plugins from Plugins Central currently load correctly or work :(

Answer (score 12):

The hex editor plugin mentioned by ellak still works, but it seems that you need the **TextFX Characters** plugin as well.

I initially installed only the hex plugin and Notepad++ would no longer pop up; instead it started eating memory (killed it at 1.2 GB). I removed it again and for other reasons installed the TextFX plugin (based on *[Find multiple lines in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489128/find-multiple-lines-in-notepad))*

Out of curiosity I installed the hex plugin again and now it works.

Note that this is on a fresh install of Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: FWIW I also had success with this recipe.