# How can I view hidden characters in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a string that has been giving some of my code fits of rage and its got "extra" characters in it that I only stumbled upon by using the arrow keys to go through it.  I noticed that the cursor stayed in place in certain areas for an extra keystroke of the arrow key.  Using View >Show Symbols > Show All Characters still didnt seem to indicate anything there.  What kind of character could be there and is there a plugin for it?

Comment: You know, when I copy comments from SO, I sometimes pick those chars up, and I check them at http://ideone.com - they appear as red dots.

Comment: You are talking perhaps about [zero-width non-joiner and zero-width space](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert) which sometimes occur in Stack Overflow comments. It depends on font how those characters and other special Unicode characters are displayed in text editor. For example a font supporting [zero-width non-joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) and [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) don't display anything for those 2 chars.

Comment: MS word'2010 shows hidden/control characters with default encoding which is very handy than notepad++ plugins for basic checks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to get a raw look, check out the [HEX-Editor Plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/) (Check the Plugin Manager for it). You'll see the character codes for everything; even non-printable characters.

I use it, and have no issues on the newer versions of Notepad++.

Comment: It seems not to be working with newer versions? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14622157/4791599

Comment: That's not true if I'm using it this moment without issues. Tested with version 6.6.9 -> 6.8.6. Also, other comments seem to agree that this isn't an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617888/a-hex-viewer-editor-plugin-for-notepad/14622157#comment43640567_14622157

Comment: I have used this before, but not on my current workstation and had forgotten about this.  Thank you.  I grabbed this plugin and can clearly see now that the two versions of the what appear to be the same string are not the same!

Comment: The latest version of the `HEX-Editor` plugin is v0.9.8 and can be accessed via `Plugins > Plugins Manager...`. Works well.

Answer (score 22):

**The simplest way is to use the menu:**

> View->Show Symbol->Show all characters

It will show Tabs and EOL characters.

Here is an example of a VBS script that announces the current hour being viewed in Notepad++ on Win7.

[image]

**Note that it is clear I used spaces to do the indents - not Tabs.**

---

> This is the base script I used in the Q&A about how to make Windows announce the time at the top of each hour:

https://superuser.com/questions/1268702/how-to-make-windows-speak-the-time-at-the-top-of-the-hour/1268703#1268703

Comment: The problem with this option is that it shows only the few most common invisible characters.  There are many, many others this does not show.

Comment: Not a good answer, %E2%80%8B character is for example hidden (LRM)

Answer (score 5):

Try to set int the menú "Encoding --> Encode to ANSI

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: Victor's answer should be taken more in consideration.
It is true that using HEX plugin helps you have some form of visualisation but changing the encoding type to ANSI will show a **?** where there is a hidden.
So this should help you.

Comment: Doing this I was able to see my text had Â where there appeared to be spaces when it was UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like [UltraEdit HEX Editor](http://www.ultraedit.com/ultraedit-tour/hex-editor.html)?

It seems it is currently not available with Notepad++, see [A hex viewer / editor plugin for Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617888/).