# Regular expression for selecting procedure of classic asp

Tags: regex, asp-classic, notepad++

How do I select a procedure written in classic asp with regular expression. 
For example:

```vb
Sub SubName
   'sub implementation having multi line statements. It may have comments also.
End Sub
```

How do I select the multi line procedure using the regular expression?

My objective: To obtain all the procedure listed in all ASP pages within a specified folder and merge it in one file. So I am searching for a regular expression that will yield procedures which I can collect and append in one file for debugging purposes.

Comment: What's your version of Notepad++? Older versions have trouble doing multiline matches in regex mode.

Comment: My notepad++ version is v6.3.2

Answer (score 2):

This will match a sub (assuming `.` matches all):

```
^\s*(Sub.*?)^\s*End Sub
```

This also assumes that there are no multiline comments, which [Lankymart assures me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901096/regular-expression-for-selecting-procedure-of-classic-asp/21903781?noredirect=1#comment-33171594) can't happen, and that both `Sub` and `End Sub` are on their own line.

Comment: VBScript doesn't support multi-line comments all lines have to start with `'`.

Comment: Sorry that does not work. it did not result any results.

Comment: Did you check the box for `.` matches newline, as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9561676/2936460)?

Comment: If you did, try `^\s*(Sub.*?End Sub)`

Answer (score 1):

How about: `Sub SubName[\s\S]*?End Sub`? See http://regex101.com/r/xP9kG3