# Notepad++ only paste first line of copied code in replace?

Tags: javascript, html, css, notepad++

I uses replace feature of notepad ++ a lot to replace code across multiple files. But recently i don't know what i did wrong whenever i paste code of multiple lines in replace textbox of notepad++, only first line of code get pasted. So i have to make all code in one line which takes lot of time and code become cumbersome. It is very difficult for me like this and i can't find any solution anywhere. Please help!

```
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({



google_ad_client: "ca-pub-9493617747666534",



enable_page_level_ads: true
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ does not natively support multi-line find and replace operations.

**Reference:** [find multiple lines in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489128/find-multiple-lines-in-notepad)

However, the *ToolBucket* plugin adds multi-line find and replace support to Notepad++: http://sumtips.com/2012/05/multiline-search-and-replace-notepad.html

**To install:**

> Download and extract zip file, and copy the NppToolBucket.dll file to
>   your Notepad++\plugins folder.
>
> You can also get this plugin from
>   within the text-editor itself by going to Plugin Manager from Plugins
>   Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager. Under the Available tab, find and select ToolBucket, and click Install.

Comment: thank you very much! I need to install plungin for multiline replace. Thank you.

Comment: @William What do you mean? It does support regex, but that is in _addition_ to regular multi-line find and replace.