# Regex to find a repeated sentence in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I need to find if the following words come more than one time in the document through Notepad++ regex search:

```
/resources/common.js
```

Given that these words could come between other words, like:

```
<script src="/resources/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So the search shows the results just if these words "/resources/common.js" are present more than one time in that file.

I need this to find in a large folder with thousands of files, just to know which files have the repeated sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your request. If you enter "/resources/common.js" in your Find tool, choose Search Mode "Normal" and click on "Find all in current document", you will get all occurrences of this string (regardless of preceding and trailing characters).

Comment: ya, but I need to find it in a big folder with thousands of files, just to know which ones have the repeated sentence.

Comment: Or are you trying to find only lines with nothing in them but your search string?

Comment: no they could have words before and after like the example after the line "Given that"

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Find in Files" tool (shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+F). Enter the search string (no regex), apply filters if desired, and choose the directory. Be sure that "In all sub-folders" is checked and hit "Find All", that should do the trick.

EDIT:
You're actually looking for multi-line regular expressions, which are not supported by notepad++ and many other regex engines. See [Multiline Regular Expression search and replace!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441044/multiline-regular-expression-search-and-replace)

Comment: I need the regex command to use it with other programs after that to edit the results

Comment: well, you don't need to use a regex, because you look for a simple string. (In other words the regex is trivial, consisting of nothing but the string you're looking for). I can only guess what it is you're looking for now, but this will find the whole line that contains the search string: .*/resources/common\.js.* Is that what you needed?

Comment: no problem if it finds the whole, as long as the string is repeated

Comment: ah, okay, I think I get it: You need a *multi-line* regex that matches only in files that contain your string more than once. Is that it?

Comment: ya, finds the string if it shows more than one time in the file, and ignores if it just one time

Comment: I'm sorry to have to inform you that Notepad doesn't support multiline regexes. See this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441044/multiline-regular-expression-search-and-replace

Comment: why this regex that I need should be multi-line?

Comment: because you want to find occurrences of the string in multiple lines of one file

Comment: I think it should be something like: find this "/resources/common.js" if it is more than once in the file..  I don't think it should have anything with multiple lines..

Comment: right, it would help you if you could tell notepad++ to ignore any files that have less than 2 hits, but I didn't find that feature. Then you could use the "Find in Files" feature, yet again without regex

Comment: ok, what is the suggested multi-line regex you are thinking of?  I'll try to use EditPad if I couldn't use NP++

Comment: That depends on what engine EditPad uses. You could try "/resources/common\.js.*/resources/common.js", but perhaps you should open a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You write about the regex, so I assume that you have access to the Unix tool-chain. Then you could use grep. The option -c reports the count:

```
grep -c cout *.cpp
bitset.cpp:1
Classes.cpp:2
ClearVectorOfUniquePtrs.cpp:2
COAP.cpp:2
ContainerCrash.cpp:0
CopyOptimisation.cpp:17
```

And another grep sorts out the zero and one matches:
`grep -c cout *.cpp | grep -v -E ":0|:1$"`

If you have Unix cut available this gives you the list of filenames:
`grep -c cout *.cpp | grep -v -E ":0|:1$" | cut -d : -f 1`

Replace `cout` with your string.